# Increase and decrease font-size limit to maximum and minimum jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, font-size

I have a jQuery script that increases or decreases the font-size and line-height of my websites CSS.

I want the increase size to be limited to three clicks, and the decrease size to only function once the increase size link has been clicked. So that the default size cannot be reduced, therefor making the lowest decrease size, the default size.

If the user changes the font-size, and navigates to another page within the site, I'd like the  "new size" to be displayed. i.e. the font-size doesn't revert to the default size.

The following script only increases and decreases the font-size and line-height:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fontResize = function (options) {
        var settings = {
            increaseBtn: $('#incfont'),
            decreaseBtn: $('#decfont')
        };
        options = $.extend(settings, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var element = $(this);
            options.increaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var baseFontSize = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
                var baseLineHeight = parseInt(element.css('line-height'));
                element.css('font-size', (baseFontSize + 2) + 'px');
                element.css('line-height', (baseLineHeight + 2) + 'px');
            });
            options.decreaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var baseFontSize = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
                var baseLineHeight = parseInt(element.css('line-height'));
                element.css('font-size', (baseFontSize - 2) + 'px');
                element.css('line-height', (baseLineHeight - 2) + 'px');
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$(function () {
    $('body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,ul,ol,a,input').fontResize();
});
```

I've created a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2x4/

Comment: If a user navigates from the page, then no configuration would be saved. You are using JS currently as client-side. If you do want it to be saved, use localStorage, sessionStorage, or cookies.

Comment: As an aside, I might also suggest writing your CSS to use ems/rems/percents relative to the font-size on the html tag (by default, it's set by the browser) which would allow you to modify the font-size in one place and have your entire design and layout change relative to that single size. Much more responsive :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variable to keep track of where you are in the font size increasing and decreasing. Here's a revised version of your fiddle, and code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fontResize = function(options){
    var increaseCount = 0;
    var self = this;

    var changeFont = function(element, amount){
      var baseFontSize = parseInt(element.css('font-size'), 10);
      var baseLineHeight = parseInt(element.css('line-height'), 10);
      element.css('font-size', (baseFontSize + amount) + 'px');
      element.css('line-height', (baseLineHeight + amount) + 'px');
    };

    options.increaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(increaseCount === 3){ return; }
      self.each(function(index, element){
        changeFont($(element), 2);
      });
      increaseCount++;
        });

    options.decreaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(increaseCount === 0){ return; }
      self.each(function(index, element){
        changeFont($(element), -2);
      });
      increaseCount--;
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $('body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,ul,ol,a,input').fontResize({
    increaseBtn: $('#incfont'),
    decreaseBtn: $('#decfont')
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2x4/7/

I also made fontResize pass the buttons in during invocation, which makes more sense if you're trying to design this as a jQuery component. Also, since the logic to change font size is repeating code, I separated that into its own function, so you don't repeat yourself.

EDIT: whoops, skimped over the part that you wanted persistence as well! That's easy enough through localStorage. Clicky here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2x4/9/

Comment: The second option caused some weird font-sizes when I navigated to another page. All the fonts were smaller than the default, even though I increased them

Comment: That's a pretty weird issue, and hard to debug in a jsFiddle. For some reason, refreshing the page is screwing with the value of `localStorage.increaseCount`. Hotfix here, but I think it's a jsfiddle issue. http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2x4/11/

Answer (score 0):

Without a backend to store the user's settings, you would need to use a cookie, sessionStorage or localStorage to save the setting on the browser.

Here's a pretty decent [jquery plugin for CRUD-ing cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Lv2x4/2/)

JavaSript Code I changed:

```
return this.each(function () {
  var element = $(this),
      clicks = 0; // add a clicks counter

  options.increaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (clicks < 3) { // make sure limit is not exceeded
      var baseFontSize = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
      var baseLineHeight = parseInt(element.css('line-height'));
      element.css('font-size', (baseFontSize + 2) + 'px');
      element.css('line-height', (baseLineHeight + 2) + 'px');
      clicks += 1; // increase by 1
    }
  });

  options.decreaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (clicks > 0) { // make sure there are clicks left
      var baseFontSize = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
      var baseLineHeight = parseInt(element.css('line-height'));
      element.css('font-size', (baseFontSize - 2) + 'px');
      element.css('line-height', (baseLineHeight - 2) + 'px');
      clicks -= 1; // decrease number of clicks left
    }
  });
```

This would work. But for the storage of user settings, you will have to use localstorage, sessionStorage, or cookies.

Comment: That works well, I just need to figure out how to use it with @rodaine suggested cookies plugin

Answer (score 0):

use two variables
            var incr=0;
            var decr=0;
and if condition to limit your font size increment to Three clicks and also consider one thing that when you click on button if other button is clicked then you need to decrease value of other variable so that you always get **three clicks** to increment/decrement font size.([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2x4/4/)  **WORKING....**)

```
            options.increaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var baseFontSize = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
            var baseLineHeight = parseInt(element.css('line-height'));

            if(incr<3){
            element.css('font-size', (baseFontSize + 2) + 'px');
            element.css('line-height', (baseLineHeight + 2) + 'px');
            incr++;                
            if(decr>0)
            {decr--;  }
            }
        });
            options.decreaseBtn.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var baseFontSize = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
            var baseLineHeight = parseInt(element.css('line-height'));

            if(decr<3){
            element.css('font-size', (baseFontSize - 2) + 'px');
            element.css('line-height', (baseLineHeight - 2) + 'px');
            decr++;
            if(incr>0)
            {incr--; }

        }
        });
```